# Webpack-simple: SASS variables don't get translated into their values on the page

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

After installing `Vue-CLI` with `webpack-simple`, then doing `npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev`, I do have a `style.scss` in my `/src folder`.

However despite following the [Vue.js docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass-vs-scss), `SCSS` doesn't work properly: if I create a `SCSS` variable `$gray1: #dddddd` then use it like `background: $gray`, `$gray` doesn't get translated into #dddddd in the browser (console shows `background: $gray1`, which of course makes no sense to Chrome).

Is there any special step to take in order to make SASS work in this case?

Content of my `Webpack.config.js` file:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {}
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true,
    clientLogLevel: 'none'
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Here is how I import my `style.scss` file in my main component:

```
<style>
@import '../style.scss';
</style>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't get applied". How are you applying it in your Vue files? (I'm assuming you're using SFC). Show how you're importing/using the scss file.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify it. Yes I use SFC. The CSS in my SCSS file gets correctly applied, but SCSS variables are not replaced by their value in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone with the same issue comes across that thread, the problem was that I forgot to specify `lang="scss"` when calling my `SCSS` file:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import './style.scss';
</style>
```

All the `CSS` contained in `style.scss` still worked. As for the `SCSS` variables defined or used in it, they didn't work. Now they do.

For some reason, nobody spotted that :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at my own configs and files, change the rule:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {}
      }
    ],
  },
```

to

```
        {
            test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
            loader: "style!css!sass"
        },
```

for your `<style>` in your SFC, you also need the lang, i.e. `<style lang="scss">`

and if you're importing, you may need to put `~` in front of your path, e.g. `@import "~../style.scss";`

Comment: Tried, getting lots of issues including "./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (5:2)"

Comment: try removing the `@import` line and see if it compiles first, if it works, then work on the import part

Comment: The import does work, because my SCSS gets complied and applied on the page. The problem is that SCSS variables aren't replaced by their values. Sorry the title was very misleading, I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed these steps:

In your webpack config import `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
```

After put your entry scss into config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['app.js', 'anotherfile.scss', './scss/your-main-file.scss'],
...
```

And in module..

```
...
module: {

    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

Fulfilling these steps and having the modules correctly installed should work for you. Good luck with that!

Comment: Thanks, but I get: "ERROR in ./src/style.scss - Module build failed: Error: 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' loader is used without the corresponding plugin". I added the content of my `webpack.config.js` in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{
  test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
  use: [isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the source right now. But if the SASS file you're exporting includes variables you are attempting to use in other SASS files/ style tags, the filename has to **start with an underscore**.

`style.scss` -> `_style.scss`

If the SASS file only *uses* SASS variables from other SASS files, then it doesn't require the starting underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the rules for sass something like this

`{
       test: /\.scss$/,
       use: [{
           loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
       }, {
           loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
       }, {
           loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
       }]
 }`

Answer (score 0):

With your rules, it should work...  If your `style.scss` is in your `src` folder, try to change your import path instead:

```html
<style lang="scss">
  @import './style.scss';
</style>
```